# Course import issue from ironwood to juniper

Tags: openedx, juniper, lms

I’m trying to import a course that has multiple videos and is hosted on an ironwood server to a newly deployed juniper server. While importing it throws the following errors in the console.
Following is the console log output

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
[2020-12-11 09:29:02,847: INFO/Worker-1] VAL: Video created with id [54454916-47e9-4769-8b41-06062d0b7e8c] and status [external]
[2020-12-11 09:29:02,860: ERROR/Worker-1] [VAL] Transcript save failed to storage for video_id “54454916-47e9-4769-8b41-06062d0b7e8c” language code “en”
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/edxval/models.py”, line 489, in create
video_transcript.transcript.save(file_name, transcript_content)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py”, line 87, in save
self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py”, line 52, in save
return self._save(name, content)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py”, line 495, in _save
self._save_content(obj, content, parameters=parameters)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py”, line 510, in _save_content
obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=put_parameters)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py”, line 513, in object_upload_fileobj
ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py”, line 431, in upload_fileobj
return future.result()
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py”, line 73, in result
return self._coordinator.result()
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py”, line 233, in result
raise self._exception
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py”, line 126, in call
return self._execute_main(kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py”, line 150, in _execute_main
return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/s3transfer/upload.py”, line 692, in _main
client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py”, line 317, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py”, line 596, in _make_api_call
request_signer=self._request_signer, context=request_context)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py”, line 242, in emit_until_response
responses = self._emit(event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response=True)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py”, line 210, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py”, line 209, in conditionally_calculate_md5
calculate_md5(params, **kwargs)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py”, line 187, in calculate_md5
binary_md5 = _calculate_md5_from_file(body)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py”, line 201, in _calculate_md5_from_file
md5.update(chunk)
```

The course is imported from ironwood deployed sever to juniper deployed server.

Comment: Note: Have already posted this question on OpenEdx discussion forums but it usually takes weeks to get a reply there so posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through all the logs and was able to track that an error occurs in `edxval` while uploading the file to the `S3 bucket`. So, I checked `edxval` release versions and version `1.4.3` is the one that fixed `S3 bucket` upload issue. I updated it and it fixed my issue.